# DVD not playing properly

Tags: dvd

What do I need to install in order to play a DVD with Ubuntu? I've just recently installed Ubuntu and have tried playing the DVD. It won't play - the only thing that shows is

```
DVD was unable to play
```

I don't know what to install to fix this.

Comment: That might work:
[HOW TO PLAY DVD IN UBUNTU 14.04](http://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/)

Comment: What kind of DVD are you talking about? Is it a regular data DVD or a video DVD that you would play in a stand-alone DVD player?

Answer (score 3):

There are patent and copyright restrictions which complicate the distribution of software to support chargeable formats.

However, there is a [workaround](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)

Comment: It would be better, if the answer reflected the essential steps. Links may die.